# Typedef-equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, typedef

I know this exact question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161477/equivalent-of-typedef-in-c), but the solution posted there doesn't seem to work for me. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Tile { Empty, White, Black };
        using Board = Tile[8,8];
```

And the error I get:

> Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

It seems the "using" clause must be moved outside the `Program` class, but my `Tile` enum doesn't exist there. So how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a name to represent a specific way of instantiating a `Tile[,]` array.

Why not just declare a method that does this?

```
Tile[,] GetBoard()
{
    return new Tile[8, 8];
}
```

Another option, though I'd consider this a little bit bizarre (not to mention hacky), would be to define a `Board` type with an implicit operator to convert to `Tile[,]`, as follows:

```
public class Board
{
    private Tile[,] tiles = new Tile[8, 8];

    public static implicit operator Tile[,](Board board)
    {
        return board.tiles;
    }
}
```

This would actually allow you to do this:

```
Tile[,] board = new Board();
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `using` like that.

You can only use for concrete types, not for 'constructors' as you have used.

Comment: Whilst correct, a workaround would have given you full marks ;) Haha

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `using` to declare a name for an array type. I don’t know why, but the C# specification doesn’t allow it.

However, you can get pretty close by simply declaring `Board` as a new type containing the array you want, for example:

```
public class Board
{
    public Tile[,] Tiles = new Tile[8,8];
}
```

Now every time you say `new Board()`, you automatically get an 8x8 array of tiles.

Comment: Well, `Board.Tiles` gives me what I want... but you're adding an extra layer that I don't want.

Comment: How so?? both his solutions return `board` as a matrix of tiles... rather than a class *containing* the matrix I want. Not quite ideal syntax, but apparently what I wanted to do isn't possible in C#, so it's close enough.