# Is there an equivalent to typedef in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, typedef

ie something like

```
typedef Dictionary<string, string> mydict;
```

I swear I have seen it but cannot find it

Comment: BTW:SO would not let me ask a nice succint question, it has to be bigger !

Comment: I don't know if it supports generic classes, but you can try the using statement.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of typedef in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161477/equivalent-of-typedef-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`using MyDict = Dictionary<String, String>` which is like defining a symbol which would be replaced by the compiler.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that it applies only for that one compile scope.

Comment: note that the using keyword summary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhdeatwt.aspx doesnt mention this use - which is why i got lost

Comment: BTW u gotta use the full class name

Comment: The type full name is required only when you have declared the "using statement" outside the namespace construct of the file otherwise not required.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of.

```
using IntList = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;
```

http://arbel.net/2004/07/07/the-hidden-c-typedef/

One issue is there is no way to #include the definition.

Answer (score 2):

use inheritance:

public class DoubleNameValueCollection : Dictionary< string, NameValueCollection > { }

Then use as if it were a typedef:

```
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add( "value1", "value2" );
DoubleNameValueCollection dblNameCol = new DoubleNameValueCollection();
dblNameCol.Add( "key1", values );
```

Or if you want to confuse others:

```
DoubleNameValueCollection dblNameCol = new DoubleNameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", new NameValueCollection 
            {
                { "value1", "value2" }
    }}};
```

Comment: Better name would be NameDoubleValueCollection

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of typedef in C#, however you could use 'using' for aliases.

Answer (score 0):

There is delegate, which is used for defining a type of method argument,

there is `using BlaBla = Full.Name.Space.Yada.Yada;`

however, the using statement is only valid in current file.