# error CS0309: The type ... must be convertible to ... in order to use it as parameter in the generic type or method

Tags: c#

I've got some different types of objects, each managed by a different manager and each object should 'know' its manager. The object manager is a generic, because the way the objects are managed is the same.
All objects inherit from BaseObject.

Here a simple example:

```
public class BaseObject<TManager> {
    public TManager manager = null;
}

public class GenericManager<T> where T : BaseObject<GenericManager<T>> {
    protected virtual T AddObject(T obj) {
        obj.manager = this;
    }
}

public class SimpleObject : BaseObject<SimpleObjectManager> {
}

public class SimpleObjectManager : GenericManager<SimpleObject> {
}
```

I get the following error in the class definition of SimpleObjectManager:

> error CS0309: The type 'SimpleObject' must be convertible to `'BaseObject<GenericManager<T>>'` in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `'GenericManager<T>'`

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Well there are more errors than just that in this code.

Comment: `BaseObject` and `BaseObject<TManager>` are two different types.

Comment: @DavidG: Sorry, i did some mistakes as i cut down the code to an example. I have corrected the code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Sorry, i did some mistakes as i cut down the code to an example. I have corrected the code.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138839/circular-generic-type-parameters

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you, that helped me!