# Is it acceptable to inherit from a class just for clarity?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose I have a template/generic class that just store key/value pairs:

```
public class GenericDatabase<Key, T>
{
 public Dictionary<Key, T> Data { get; set; }               

 public GenericDatabase()
 {
   Data = new Dictionary<Key, T>();
 }
 ...
}
```

Is it acceptable to derive a class from it without introducing any new methods or member variables, just for clarity? For instance, say I want to have a character database:

```
public class CharacterDatabase : GenericDatabase<string, CharacterStat>
{
   // no new methods or member variables
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IMO** Introducing a level of inheritance for the sake of clarity would confuse other developers. I think Generic declaration is clear enough.

```
GenericDatabase<string, CharacterStat>
```

Comment: I would like to understand better; why would it be confusing?

Comment: @Extrakun, Suppose I am going to use your class in my code, then just by typing the class name `CharacterDatabase`, I won't be able to see if it is inherited from a generic class, Since you have the generic class in your code, I suppose you would use it for multiple types. Leaving it as a Generic class will let the developer know that there are other possible types which could interact with your class `GenericDatabase`.

Answer (score 1):

Its a different language.. but take a look at [how c++ defines its `std::string` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

Just wanted to point out that this practise is not just common, but used by standard library writers themselves.

I would support such a step if you are going to use `CharacterDatabase` a significant number of times. Additionally I am not sure if C# provides any other simpler mechanism than inheritance for this (like C++'s `typedef`) but that would be prefered.

[The using directive can be used like a typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161477/equivalent-of-typedef-in-c-sharp), but it affects only the file it is declared in.

```
using CharacterDatabase = GenericDatabase<string, CharacterStat>
```

Comment: @Antonijn I would assume such things would transcend language borders.. Is there a reason this is frowned upon in the C# world?

Comment: typedefs are uncommon in C# and are generally avoided.

Answer (score 1):

In OOP nothing would prevent you from doing that. However, I've seen in many places that they use *Marker Interfaces* rather than a base class to indicate something. Marker interfaces usually has no public member and would only be used to mark a class *as an example of something*.

You can take a look at these links:

[Wikipedia => marker interface pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)

[What is a marker interface](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=224126)

Comment: I haven't worked with Java, thus I really don't know. But as the name suggests, `Cloneable` means that you should be able to call `instance.Clone()` method. Thus it shouldn't be actually a marker interface.

Comment: What you suggest is what most developers would (justifiably) think.  However, it is a marker interface with no methods.

Comment: Which is much lamented. Introducing a Cloneable interface which doesn't actually have a Clone() method was a huge mistake. (Although, even if it did have a Clone() method, it'd still be messed up because there's no way to differentiate between deep and shallow cloning.)

Answer (score 1):

For me it depends of concrete types used.

If I had

```
GenericDatabase<string, CharacterStat>
```

I would leave it as it is - it is clear.
But if I had

```
GenericDatabase<string, ArrayList<Pair<CharacterStat,Integer> > >
```

then I would definitely give it a name, and a really explanatory one ;).