# Why is TimeSpan not a typedef of Int64?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, language-design

`System.TimeSpan` class only has one non-static private field and that is

```
internal long _ticks;
```

So it only keeps ticks and performs all operations (`Add`, `Subtract`, `TotalSeconds` ...) and overloads operators (`>=`, `>`, `==`) based on that private field, `_ticks`.

I see that there was no exception methods in .NET 1.0 but TimeSpan was already there but cannot it be redesigned as an alias of `Int64` and other members implemented as extension methods? This way the memory footprint would be less right?

(Same applies for `Url` class?) Any thoughts?

Comment: What would be the advantage of making TimeSpan a typedef of Int64, exactly? Just the memory footprint?

Comment: The same applies to `DateTime`? I don't see any value in making that. And btw. extension methods were added in .NET 3.5

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: wait.. what is the difference between long and int64 ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's enough. We live in an age of gigabytes of memory in a tiny tiny tiny laptop computer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that's not 100% accurate. `DateTime` keeps both `ticks` and `kind`, so that's 2 fields.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I don't think language designers usually think so. There are companies out there using their own string classes etc. And not all code runs on computers with GBs of memory.

Comment: @Fredou none in this context I suppose.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan That's what the Compact Framework exists for though. If you're running within a memory constrained environment, then thats what you would go for. You have more to worry about than the space of a `TimeSpan` if you're in these sorts of environments. The rest of the CLR's footprint for example.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan `DateTime.Kind` is calculated from the same fields actual date and time are calculated.

Comment: Why would the memory footprint be any less if you had a bare `long`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one thing [there is no equivalent of TYPEDEF in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/161484/120955), so it would make Timespans incredibly difficult to work with.

TimeSpan provides a whole bunch of useful properties and methods, like `.TotalHours` that wouldn't make sense on an `Int64`, so simply making it an alias of `Int64` wouldn't make much sense.

Also, I'm not entirely certain that there would be a significant (if any) difference in the class's footprint. `TimeSpan` is a struct, which means it will probably be implemented to have roughly the same footprint as its component pieces (in this case an `Int64`). (Can anybody help me find a reference to back up this impression?)

Besides that, saying that a `TimeSpan` is exactly the same thing as a `long` is just unintuitive and wrong. It increases the chance of error, where people pass a `long` into a parameter that should be a `TimeSpan`, and vice versa. Conceptually, it really goes against the grain of object-oriented programming.

I'm sure if I thought long enough about it, I could think of half a dozen other reasons (like preventing future improvements on the `TimeSpan` class that involve the introduction of another field, etc.), but these are probably more than sufficient.

Comment: But there is some sort of aliasing, right? Like long <--> int64, string <--> String that compiler handles?

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan: Yeah, but that wouldn't give you access to properties like `.TotalHours`, since there's no such property on an Int64.

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan: each of the compilers has a small set of synonyms, but they are not typedef aliases and you cannot define your own. I suggested this as a new feature early on, but it was hard to come up with good reasons why.

Comment: @david.pfx: I imagine we'll be able to do more "language-tweaking" with Roslyn. It'll probably be horribly abused by some people. :-)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Do you think? I don't really get Roslyn yet, but I had never thought it was an opportunity to change the fundamentals. Maybe I should look deeper.

Comment: @david.pfx: There's a lot to Roslyn, and I haven't fully wrapped my head around it either, but I think I remember an example that actually tweaks the language slightly. Adding a new alias keyword, for example, probably wouldn't be very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Well, C# doesn't have `typedef`'s, though you can alias a type, but that's irrelevant.  If `TimeSpan` were simply an `Int64`, then what, they should create a static `TimeSpanHelper` class with [all of the methods and properties that TimeSpan exposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

That seems silly when you can just create a type which actually functions as a time span.  A type which can override operators to allow for fluid and intuitive usage.  A type which, you know, fits in well with C#'s type system.  What you propose is more akin to C than C#.