# C# Custom alias of dictionary of structs

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, typedef

(Apologies, this is basically my first C# program, and I'm translating C++)

I defined a "user" struct like this:

```
struct user
{
  string usrnm;
  string pw;
}
```

It is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161477/equivalent-of-typedef-in-c-sharp) that one can create a pseudo typedef in C#

```
namespace _1._0
{
  class Program
  {
    struct user
    {
      string usrnm;
      string pw;
    }
    using (userArr = Dictionary<int, user>);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work; it throws me the error saying:

`Invalid token 'using' in class, struct or interface member declaration`

and

`The type or namespace name 'userArr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)`

So why doesn't this work, and how can I get it to work?

Comment: As the error message says, put the `using` declaration outside of that class declaration.

Comment: add the word 'using' before the line namespace _1._0. So it will be

using namespace _1._0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Coming from a C++ background, where everything needs to be declared beforehand, I assumed I would have to do the same with C#, but I don't.

Placing the `using` statement before the `struct user` declaration works fine.

(Sidenote: I removed all such "typedefs" from my code")

Answer (score 2):

The full example should be:

```
using userArr = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, _1._0.Program.user>;

namespace _1._0
{ 
    // You could place it here, nearly equivalent:
    // using userArr = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, Program.user>;

    public class Program
    {
        public struct user
        {
            string usrnm;
            string pw;
        }
    }
}
```

and then inside that file you can:

```
userArr myDictionary = new userArr();
```

You use the `using` like `using System;`, not like `using (something) {}`. That one is another type of `using` :), so you can place it outside a `namespace` declaration or directly inside a `namespace` declaration. Not inside a `class`/`struct`/method body. Note that, as written by Jeppe, you have to use the full namespace for `Dictionary<>`.

Note that this `using` will "work" only inside the file where you "used" it. Clearly you can reapply it to other source files.

But note that **I concur with CodeCaster**. The only time I use the `using ... =` is when I have classes with the same name in multiple namespaces and I need to be able to distinguish between them (for example I have `MyNamespace1.MySubnamespace1.MyClass` and `MyNamespace2.MySubnamespace2.MyClass`... I could every time write the full name or I could add two `using M1 = MyNamespace1.MySubnamespace1;using M2 = MyNamespace2.MySubnamespace2;` and then `M1.MyClass` and `M2.MyClass`)

Comment: In the `using` alias directive in the top, can one really leave out the namespace for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I was not including "system" namespaces. But then, as written, the example could compile (with the addition of that namespace) but it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Even with an earlier `using` directive, the `using` you show will not work. You need the full name of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>`. **Edit:** If you move the `using` alias inside the `namespace` and keep the `using System.Collections.Generic;` outside, it appears to work with only `using userArr = Dictionary<int, Program.user>;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Fascinating... I didnt know... If I think about it for a moment, it's clear why... You can't do `using System; using Collections;`... The `using` don't use other `using`

Answer (score 1):

Leave the C++ methodologies at C++. You don't need any of this.

Just use a class with properties and use the proper syntax to instantiate the dictionary.

```
namespace _1._0
{
    public class User
    {
      public string Username { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }      
    }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userDictionary = new Dictionary<int, User>();
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know *why* you want to use an alias, but if it's to prevent typing long type names multiple times, check out `var` as used above.

Comment: I'll add "and remember that you can often use the `var` keyword when you don't want to write the same long things too many times" :-) (as you've done)