# Convert Generic Class to Its Inherited Class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I am refactoring an old library with some class like the following one:

```
public class Template  //Old one
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now it's better to provide more flexibility to allow user defined `Value` type. So I changed `Template` to a generic class:

```
public class Template<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This change breaks the usages of old `Template` class from others, so I tried to add backward compatibility (allows others to use my library in the old way) with:

```
public class Template: Template<double> { }
```

But it also requires lots of changes in the library. Especially where the old `Template` is used, such as:

```
public class AnotherClassInLibrary<T>
{
    public Template<T> API() {...}
}

public class AnotherClassInLibrary : AnotherClassInLibrary<double>
{
    // This class is also defined for the old way of using the library
    public Template API()
    {
         return base.API();
         // Error here: Template<double> cannot be implicitly convert to Template.
    }
}
```

So here comes the problem: the new `Template` is inherited from `Template<double>`, so casting is not a good/working practice here. Is there a work around to keep `AnotherClassInLibrary` backward compatible while not rewrite the `API()` code twice?

P.S. I really hope C# has something like `typedef` in C++. But [the answer is NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161477/equivalent-of-typedef-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Where is your non-generic `Template` class?

Comment: what if another type implemented `Template<double>`, would you still want that cast to be valid?

Comment: _"Though `Template` is exactly a `Template<double>`"_ - no it's not, it's one class deeper into the inheritance chain.

Comment: You are trying to cast from a parent to a child. What if you had `Template<int> a`? Do you still want to be able to cast it?

Comment: @rory.ap The original code is quite complex so I tried to put simplified code here. You can think the original Template class as: public class Template
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

Comment: For this to work `Template<T>` would need to inherit from whatever `Template` is.

Comment: Just because you supply no new functionality, that still doesn't make `Template` some kind of *synonym* or *alias* for the type `Template<double>`. They're distinct types.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No I don't. I just want to add backward compatibility to only double type.

Comment: @MoonyChou It is backwards compatible; you can always implicitly convert a type to its base types.  You want it to be forwards compatible.  That doesn't work.  You can't treat something as a more derived type than it is.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Good question! I think the answer is yes for my purpose. In my case I just want to convert a base template class to a corresponding inherited class.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are exactly right in C# programming language logic :D

Comment: @DavidG I can modify the old Template class as much as I want. But it's hard for me to change the code that uses the old Template public members.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes you are right. I've just rewrite my question to demonstrate why I did all these weird things...

Comment: Have you considered having an `ITemplate<T>` *interface* that both `Template` and `Template<T>` implement (and no inheritance between the classes). Difficult to know if it'll help without knowing your use cases.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It also will require changing of the exisiting code so it'll use the interface. If he did think it previously - yes, but if no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your `Template` class inherits from `Template<double>`, it's not the same. Conside you will change the defintion of `Template` as follows:

```
public class Template : Template<double>
{
    public int AddedMember { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you try to execute the previous code. You're trying to convert a class with some properties, to a class with more properties - you'll access to incorect places in the memory!

You always can convert a class to its base class, because the drived class contains all the base class' memebers. So, explicit conversion is not needed. However, when you're trying to convert a base class to a drived class, the convert will success only if the base class variable points to an instance of the drived class, and so, all the memebers of the drived class are exist. If no, an `InvalidCastException` will thrown at runtime. So, explicit cast is required (because one of the guidlines why to use an explicit cast is to use an explicit cast if the cast may fail).

So, if you'll change your code so the variable a (of type `Template<double>`), the convert will success:

```cs
Template<double> a = new Template();
Template b = (Template)a; // No exception will thrown
```

The last code will success beacuse the variable `a` points to an instance of `Template` (and not of `Template<double>`), so we sure (at runtime) that all the members of `Template` is exist and no error will occur.

#### Edit:

After you said your requirements, I can help you. What you want? you want to enable convert of `Template` to `Template` - this is possible with [user-defined conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/conversion-operators).

But, custom conversions between drived class and base class are not allowed. So, there are two solutions:

1. `Template` won't inherit from `Template<double>`, as follows:

```cs
    public class Template<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Template
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }
        
        public static explicit operator Template(Template<double> generic) // Or implicit instead of explicit
        {
            return new Template { Value = generic.Value };
        }
    }

    var generic = new Template<double> { Value = 1234.56 };
    var nongeneric = (Template)generic; // Or Template nongeneric = generic; if the conversion defined as implicit
```

2. You won't define a custom conversion, and instead, you'll define a regular method (I defined a constructor):

```cs
    public class Template<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Template : Template<double>
    {
        public Template(Template<double> generic)
        {
            this.Value = generic.Value;
        }
    }
    
    var generic = new Template<double> { Value = 1234.56 };
    var nongeneric = new Template(generic);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are many shared methods between Template<T> and Template, so I chose the second solution yesterday after many trials. Hope your answer would help others with similar questions :D